# expression or statement?:'if a : do_something()' or '(a and do_somthing())',which is better?

Tags: python, coding-style, expression

i found that python can easily coding in 'lisp' style.

## exp:

normal way:

```
if a:
    do_something()
```

'function' way:

```
(a and do_something())
```

normal way:

```
if not a:
    do_somthing()
elif b:
    do_otherthing()
```

'function' way

```
((not a and do_something()) or (b and do_otherthing()))
```

normal way:

```
a = bla.get_a()
if a is None:
    a = A()
```

'function' way:

```
a = (bla.get_a() or A())
```

this feature is so fascinating that i can coding in one line which must write in several lines in the normal way.

but i don't know is it 'pythonic' or worse than usual.

google coding stype also not defined which is more compliance with the rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "function way" you mean "this looks a bit like LISP," sure, you've surrounded your code with parentheses and removed colons. But that doesn't make this a "functional" programming style any more than it makes the parenthetical statement a list. Essentially, you're exploiting the short-circuit property of logical operators to make your code a little harder to read.

Also, the code samples in your second example aren't actually logically identical. If `a` is false and `do_something()` returns a false value (which includes `None`, the value automatically returned if there is no explicit return statement), then the `or` won't actually short-circuit, and if `b` is true, then `do_otherthing()` will also be executed.

Comment: Well, you really shouldn't do that anyway, because it's difficult to read. But you could just do the following: `((not a and (do_something() or True)) or (b and do_otherthing()))`

Comment: You're welcome. However, and I don't mean to sound rude here, but as a way of saying "thank you," comments aren't really encouraged; instead, upvote or accept (an) answer(s).  http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126180/is-it-acceptable-to-write-a-thank-you-in-a-comment, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer

Comment: oh..i see...i will vote next time when i have the enough vote

Comment: oh..sorry..i hope i didn't make some big mistake...i am new here...and  did not know the rules...

Comment: No problem! Thank you. You might want to go ahead and read the faq, though, just so you understand the site better: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 7):

Definitely

```
if a: 
    do_something()
```

The second one (`a and do_somthing())`) is horrible and hacky. As @limelights said, The Zen of Python says *Explicit is better than implicit* and *readability counts*. You should probably read [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) if you haven't already.

Comment: Also, Zen of Python says `Explicit is better than implicit` and `readability counts`.

Comment: @Matthias Agreed, I'll change it

Answer (score 3):

`((not a and do_something()) or (b and do_otherthing()))` is different from

```
if not a:
    do_somthing()
elif b:
    do_otherthing()
```

in the following way:

If `do_something()` returns a false value, the second expression `(b and do_otherthing())` gets evaluated as well.

Expressions which work like this should use the [`b if a else c` syntax](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) introduced with Python 2.5:

```
do_somethind() if not a else (b and do_otherthing())
```

But, as in your case you do not need the result, you should refrain from doing so and better use the statement syntax with the `:`.

Comment: it looks like the list expression.